# Typescript error Cannot find module 'typescript-Collections' when changing the module to "umd" or "amd" in tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, amd, umd

I am using VS17 Enterprise. I can easily import "[typescript-collections](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections)" (as instructed on this page) if I had set my `module` option to `commonjs` in my `tsconfig.json`.

However, as soon as I change it to **"umd"** or **"amd"**, I get error (see the screenshot please) saying that `Cannot find module 'typescript-collections'` and therefore, the two variables `queue` and `queue1` will be of type `any`. I have also attached my `tsconfig.json`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey, I'm also having this issue! Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I have not yet. I ended up creating my own module.

Comment: @SadraAbedinzadeh Is there a particular reason you want to use `umd` or `amd` module resolution?

Comment: @xiaodeaux, No, but why not? If i change my settings to use `amd` or `commonJs` some other modules will throw errors. Isn't it true that the whole point of using `umd` is to get rid of these problems ?

Comment: @SadraAbedinzadeh I'm not sure honestly.

Answer (score 0):

As of today this problem with this package remains and my solution was to use es6 as my module

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "module":"es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

and then import the classes using the notation below -

`import * as Collections from 'typescript-collections/src/lib';`

It seems there is an issue with this dependency packaging.

Comment: even this results in compilation error i.e. index.ts needs to be a part of the package or similar error message. I ended up copying all the classes to my project source folder to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by explicitly specifying the `moduleResolution` compiler option.

```
{
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

Apparently the `moduleResolution` is set to `"node"` automatically, **if `module` is set to `"commonjs"`**. The Typescript compiler seems to use another resolution strategy otherwise.

[A post in a GitHub issue thread led me to this idea.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6364#issuecomment-169392641)